# how can i store two info on a single select and call them in separate textbox HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<span id="s_home_country">                   
    <select name="Home Country" id="home_country">
        <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option value="h1">Home1</option>
        <option value="h2">Home2</option>
        <option value="h3">Home3</option>
        <option value="h4">Home4</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

and I have another data that i want to incorporate, when `Home1` is selected, I want this to show `21-dec` into another textbox automatically. and so on..

```
var Home_country = [
    "21-Dec",
    "01-Jan",
    "01-Jan",
    "01-Jan",
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object and an event listener.

```js
var home_country = {
    "h1":"21-Dec",
    "h2":"01-Jan",
    "h3":"01-Jan",
    "h4":"01-Jan",
};

var selectbox = document.getElementById('home_country');
var textbox = document.getElementById('home_country_date');

selectbox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  textbox.value = home_country[this.value]
})
```

```html
<span id="s_home_country">                   
    <select name="Home Country" id="home_country">
        <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option value="h1">Home1</option>
        <option value="h2">Home2</option>
        <option value="h3">Home3</option>
        <option value="h4">Home4</option>
    </select>
</span>

<input type="text" id="home_country_date">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below snippet just add another attribute `data-attr1` and on change of select list find selected option and get its attribute with name `data-attr1` and pass attribute's value to textbox

```js
$("#home_country").on("change",function(){
 $(".txtvalue").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-attr1"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="s_home_country">                   
    <select name="Home Country" id="home_country">
        <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option data-attr1="21-Dec" value="h1">Home1</option>
        <option data-attr1="01-Dec" value="h2">Home2</option>
        <option data-attr1="02-Dec" value="h3">Home3</option>
        <option data-attr1="03-Dec" value="h4">Home4</option>
    </select>
</span>

<input type="text" class="txtvalue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to your select input which outputs the relevant value from your array when an option is selected:

```
var el = document.getElementById('home_country');
var textbox = document.getElementById('your_textbox_el');

el.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if (e.target.value == 'h1') {
      textbox.value = Home_country[0];
    } else if (e.target.value == 'some other condition') {
      // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can just put the values of the `Home_country` array inside the `value` properties of the options like so:

```
<span id="s_home_country">                   
  <select name="Home Country" id="home_country">
    <option value="Select one" selected="selected">Select one</option>
    <option value="21-Dec">Home1</option>
    <option value="01-Jan">Home2</option>
    <option value="01-Jan">Home3</option>
    <option value="01-Jan">Home4</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Now, when you do get the value of your `select` element, it will be the value in the array that you gave.